# Trouble re(deploying) to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github

I had trouble re-deploying the sample app from Hartls book:

```
 !  No such app as murmuring-beyond-6630.
```

So then I logged into Heroku, deleted the app and created another...

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
yuliya@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ heroku create

Creating cryptic-plains-9409... done, stack is cedar
http://cryptic-plains-9409.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:cryptic-plains-9409.git

yuliya@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ heroku keys:add
Found existing public key: /home/yuliya/.ssh/yuliya.pub
Uploading SSH public key /home/yuliya/.ssh/yuliya.pub... done

yuliya@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ git push heroku master

 !  No such app as murmuring-beyond-6630.
```

Still referenced previous app so I removed it using the git rm heroku command.  Then I ran heroku create.  Then tried to push the app again...

```
yuliya@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:cryptic-plains-9409
yuliya@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ git push heroku master

 !  Invalid path.
 !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.
```

I am completely stuck and would appreciate any help here.  I am brand new to this, and thank you for your time!

Comment: did you do git remote rm heroku?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you left off the `.git`, which is what the error is complaining about.

Try this,

```
git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:cryptic-plains-9409.git
git push heroku master
```

Referenced this question:
[How does "git push heroku master" know where to push to and how to push to a different repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338551/how-does-git-push-heroku-master-know-where-to-push-to-and-how-to-push-to-a-dif)